# How to display WMI data in a DataGridView

Tags: c#

I am trying to display some data in `DataGridView` but it's not being displayed. I then tried displaying it in a `ListBox` and it works. How I can I get it to work in the `DataGridView`.

```
   ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Service");

    foreach (ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
       {
           listBox1.Items.Add(mo["Name"].ToString());
           listBox2.Items.Add(mo["Description"].ToString());
           listBox3.Items.Add(mo["DispalyName"].ToString());
           listBox4.Items.Add(mo["ServiceType"].ToString());

       }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your DataGridView you have to add at least four columns to display the results.

```
  ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_Service");

  grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
  grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
  grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());
  grid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn());

  foreach (ManagementObject mo in mc.GetInstances())
  {
    object col1 = mo["Name"] != null ? mo["Name"].ToString() : null;
    object col2 = mo["Description"] != null ? mo["Description"].ToString() : null;
    object col3 = mo["DisplayName"] != null ? mo["DisplayName"].ToString() : null;
    object col4 = mo["ServiceType"] != null ? mo["ServiceType"].ToString() : null;

    grid.Rows.Add(new object[] { col1, col2, col3, col4 });
  }
```